# document.getElementById(...).... not properly grabbing my text from the table

Tags: javascript

HTML/JavaScript n00b here.

I have a table whose bottom row is composed of input cells:

```
<table class="convtbl" id="table1">

   <tr>
      <td>Distance 1 (in miles)</td>
      <td>Time 1 (hh:mm:ss)</td>
      <td>Distance 2 (in miles)</td>
      <td>Time 2 (hh:mm:ss)</td> 
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td><input type="text"/></td>
      <td><input type="text"/></td>
      <td><input type="text"/></td>
      <td><input type="text"/></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

I'm trying to make a function that changes the values inside the input cell. I haven't fully made the function, but as a test I used an alert to see if the text was properly grabbed out of column 1. Apparently it wasn't, because the alert is `undefined`. Any idea why?

```
function tdconvert()
{
    var d1 = document.getElementById("table1").rows.item(1).cells.item(0).firstChild.textConent;
    var t1 = document.getElementById("table1").rows.item(1).cells.item(1).firstChild.textConent;
    var d2 = document.getElementById("table1").rows.item(1).cells.item(2).firstChild.textConent;
    var t2 = document.getElementById("table1").rows.item(1).cells.item(3).firstChild.textConent;
    alert(d1);
}
```

Comment: The property is `textContent`, whereas you have `textConent` (note the missing "t"), AND, to get the value of an input box, use `value`. Please check your code for typographical errors before posting :)

Comment: You could try using .innerHTML instead of textContent if fixing the spelling doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Those are inputs, you probably meant `element.value`, not `textConent`, it should at least by `textContent` if that's what you're trying to get.

```
var d1 = document.getElementById("table1").rows.item(1).cells.item(0).firstChild.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing textContent attribute of textbox, thats the reason its throwing undefined. 
Try value attribute of textbox

document.getElementById("table1").rows.item(1).cells.item(0).firstChild.value;

It works i tested